# How to pass value from directive link to html using this( without using scope)

Tags: angularjs

i want to pass value from directive link to my html file. I am not using scope.

```
  app.directive('isolate', function () {      
  return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      link: function (element, attrs) {
        var This = this;
        This.testlinkdata = 'data';
        }
  };
```

});

in the above code i want to access testlinkdata in html

```
<h4>Test Link: {{testlinkdata}}</h4>
```

if i do so i am not getting any value
Here is my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/WtUfji1utl7AvaGDxcec?p=preview

how can i access local variable without scope?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you do not want to use scope. FYI: Scope has been developed for this purpose.

Comment: scope is not used in our project. i want to implement using this